# Adding direct contact to the "Share via" menu

Tags: contacts, share-menu

The [Share via menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) is awesome.

But in more than half of the cases I use the menu to share something with my wife, and the question is not what to "share it via" but who to "share it with".

I simply wish there was a setting where I could predefine a contact from address book and preferred way of "sharing via" per action (email in most of the cases) that will appear in the "share via" menu.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Some easy way to share with your starred contacts would make a lot of sense. Would be nice if GMail had a quick way to select a Starred contact without having to go type them out or go through Contacts.

Comment: I added this [Android enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24741)